# How to control size of journals in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to control the size of large journals files as journal file take large amount of space. How can the space can be saved using small files.

Comment: All you need to do is `--smallfiles` but I haven't worked with Mongo in a while now...

Comment: How much space is the journal taking up? The journal should not be taking up very much space compared to the data. I think there's an underlying problem here.

Comment: Did you change the [syncPeriodSecs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.syncPeriodSecs) parameter? This could be the only reason I could think of why the journal should grow to "take a large amount of disk space".

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research:

[Setting smallfiles option for controlling journaling doesn't control the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495587/setting-smallfiles-option-for-controlling-journaling-doesnt-control-the-size)

However the command is `--smallfiles`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to control journal file size,

1. Use `--smallfiles` option in mongod which will use 128MB as max size of journal file instead of 1GB
2. `ulimit` is way in unix to control system settings. It will allow you to set max. file size in system. Consider this when you have sharding in place.
3. Reduce `commitIntervalMs` to a lower value i.e flush data to disk frequently. Use this option only when you can tolerate heavy IO load periodically.